# Setting max zoom in mapbox map?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

```
     mapObject = L.mapbox.map('mapDiv')
     .setView(defaultLocation,defaultZoom)
      .addControl(L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places'));


             L.mapbox.styleLayer('mapbox://styles/gauravcatstech/civ82vos7008f2is5x92cp     vye').addTo(mapObject);

          L.control.scale({maxWidth: 100,metric: true, imperial: false}).addTo(mapObject);
```

How would i set max zoom in mapbox map..i have try object.maxZoome but sitt not able to set maxzoom

Answer (score 6):

You can set it with `options` attribute during map initialization like this:

```
var options = {
  maxZoom: 13
};
mapObject = L.mapbox.map('mapDiv', undefined, options);
```

Details in the [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.4.0/l-mapbox-map/)