# Mapbox GL JS set Max Zoom level not working?

Tags: javascript, web-mapping, mapbox, zoom, mapbox-gl-js

I cant seem to get my map to set a max zoom level.

Here is a snippit of my code -

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', 
style: 'mapbox://styles/cdickinson11/cjg49l1f305ou2rls3hd65a6s', 
center: [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923], 
zoom: 10
options.maxZoom: 13
});
```

I also tried this, adapted from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/217678/setting-max-zoom-in-mapbox-map). It did not work either, I'm guessing because it is from mapbox js instead of mapbox gl js.

```
var options = {
maxZoom: 13
};
mapObject = L.mapbox.map('mapDiv', undefined, options);
```

I'm fairly new to this type of thing. I'm pretty sure my issue lies in a lack of basic understanding about javascript, and about the difference between mapbox gl js and mapbox js. Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try just (**edit:** I missed a comma, fixed it now)

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', 
style: 'mapbox://styles/cdickinson11/cjg49l1f305ou2rls3hd65a6s', 
center: [-77.034084142948, 38.909671288923], 
zoom: 10,
maxZoom: 13
});
```

Here is a JSBin demonstrating it: https://jsbin.com/qodovogevi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: yes I did and it did not work. not sure why?

Comment: Oops, I forgot there should be a comma after the zoom option! I'll edit that into the answer.